how to sort all files in a directory, including subdirectories, with a certain extension by last to first modified?
I'm able to find all files with a certain extension in a directory, including sub-directories, like this
find . -type f -regex ".*\.py" > temp.txt

and write it in temp.txt. By running
xargs ls -ltrd < temp.txt > sorted.txt

I sort them by access time and store it in sorted.txt, however I would like to do it by modified time, how?

AFAIK, ls -lt actually sorts by modification time by default - you'd need -u or --time=atime (or --time=access or --time=use) to sort by access time.

If you switch to the Z shell (zsh) you can use glob qualifiers to order by modification time directly:
print -rC1 **/*.py(om) > sorted.txt

To order oldest first, change o to O. The recursive glob ** avoids the need for find.
If you have to use another shell then find can print timestamps so you don't need ls:
find . -name '*.py' -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -z -rn | 
  cut -z -f1 --complement | xargs -r0 -n1 > sorted.txt


@kos oops thank you - I really should resist the urge to post before coffee ;)

Don't tell me :)

I don't think you should include this in the answer BTW (we don't even know OP's purpose in doing this), just a note to others... Lately I've been using printf '%q' to make lists like these reusable in scripts, in case of the never-occurring newline in the filename

A minor point: You don't need to use regex to find your .py files. Use -name '*.py'
